# Filter array of objects for unique elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of objects:

```
var arr = [
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "baz" },
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "qux" },
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "baz" },
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "qux" },
  {a: "bar", b: "foo", c: "qux" },
  {a: "bar", b: "qux", c: "foo" },
  {a: "bar", b: "foo", c: "qux" }
];
```

The array shall be filtered so only the unique objects remain:

```
var arr = [
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "baz" },
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "qux" },
  {a: "bar", b: "foo", c: "qux" },
  {a: "bar", b: "qux", c: "foo" }
];
```

For arrays of plain strings, I use

```
arr.filter(function (value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

but this doesn't work on objects. All properties must be compared in my case. I guess some sort of deep comparision is needed?

Comment: You can concatenate each object value with a delimiter and can add it to a temporary array (Make sure index is same). Then you can compare it and remove it from main array.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/791gqw27/

Comment: Whoever wants to reopen it: could you please tell the community why you think it's not a duplicate?

Comment: @zerkms the duped question is for deep object comparision, which is likely needed, but doesn't contain a full answer to my question.

Comment: @silverwind you already know how to filter don't you? If you know how to filter strings, how is it different from filtering objects?

Comment: @zerkms I'm not sure how the function supplied to `Array.prototype.filter`  should look given I already have the `deepCompare` function.

Comment: @silverwind that's trivial: you iterate over `arr` from `index + 1` up to `arr.length - 1` and check if the `value` is equal to `arr[i]`. If it is - you return `false`, otherwise you return `true` in the end of the function.

Comment: @zerkms not sure about `index + 1`, because that would be out of bounds for the last element. Here's what I have right now: http://jsfiddle.net/sygrp9u0/1/

Comment: @silverwind it will not be: `for (var i = index + 1; i < arr.length - 1; ++i) {}` will never get out of bounds http://jsfiddle.net/sygrp9u0/4/

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, that looks to work flawlessly, even with different sorting, I'd accept that comment as an answer if I could :)

Comment: @silverwind it's still a duplicate :-) The application is not that relevant

Comment: @zerkms I don't agree with that duplicate, as there the other answer only points to a method that can be used to solve this, there's probably a few clever ways to do this besides a deep-equal. I also noticed your solution doesn't filter correctly in some cases, but I'll just write something up tailored to my use case now.

Comment: And here's my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/sygrp9u0/7/

Comment: @silverwind "doesn't filter correctly in some cases" --- in what "other" cases?

Comment: @zerkms: Here's your last answer, updated with my shuffled array: http://jsfiddle.net/sygrp9u0/8/ - Note it contains `"a": "foo", "c": "baz", "b": "bar"` twice.

Comment: @silverwind it's a trivial off-by-one mistake: http://jsfiddle.net/sygrp9u0/9/

Answer (score 0):

If your objects all have the same keys, you can use lodash's or underscore's `_.findWhere` function:

> Performs a deep comparison between each element in collection and the source object, returning the first element that has equivalent property values.

```js
var arr = [
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "baz" },
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "qux" },
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "baz" },
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "qux" },
  {a: "bar", b: "foo", c: "qux" },
  {a: "bar", b: "qux", c: "foo" },
  {a: "bar", b: "foo", c: "qux" }
];

function uniqueObjects(arr) {
  var u = [];
  arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (!_.findWhere(u, obj)) {
      u.push(obj);
    }
  });
  return u
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(uniqueObjects(arr),null,2);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.7.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id='result'></pre>
```

If not, a deep comparison can be made by using `_.matches` both ways:

```js
var arr = [
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "baz" },
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "qux" },
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "baz" },
  {a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "qux" },
  {a: "bar", b: "foo", c: "qux" },
  {a: "bar", b: "qux", c: "foo" },
  {a: "bar", b: "foo", c: "qux" },
  // Missing property
  {a: "foo", b: "bar" },
  // Ordering
  {a: "foo", c: "qux" },
  {c: "qux", a: "foo" }
];

function uniqueObjects(arr) {
  var u = [];
  arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (!u.filter(deepCompare(obj)).length) {
      u.push(obj);
    }
  });
  return u;
}

function deepCompare(obj) {
  return function(source) {
    return _.matches(obj)(source) && _.matches(source)(obj);
  };
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(uniqueObjects(arr),null,2);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.7.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id='result'></pre>
```

Comment: `_.findWhere` does not guarantee the elements equality, it just checks the provided attributes. Eg: `{a: 1}` would be found as the `{a: 1, b: 2}` object

Comment: Thanks, bad assumption that all the objects would have all the same keys. Updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

I have used the approach i have mentioned in my comment.

```js
var arr = [
  {c: "baz", a: "foo", b: "bar" },
  {c: "qux", a: "foo", b: "bar" },
  {c: "baz", b: "bar", a: "foo" },
  {c: "qux", b: "bar", a: "foo" },
  {a: "bar", c: "qux", b: "foo" },
  {a: "bar", c: "foo", b: "qux" },
  {a: "bar", b: "foo", c: "qux" }
];

var modified = arr.map(function (value) {
    var result = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(value).sort();

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        result.push(value[keys[i]]);
    }
    return result.join('');
});

for (var i = (modified.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    if (modified.indexOf(modified[i]) !== i) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}


alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: What if some values already have `,` as a part? The solution is prone to give false positive matches.

Comment: @zerkms Update the code not to use any delimiter

Comment: "Update the code not to use any delimiter" --- what does it mean? Your code may give false positives.

Comment: This looks to work for my case, but I can see it failing in cases where the properties are ordered differently.

Comment: @silverwind I rearranged the properties. Still i am seeing the same result. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4fqeshf/). Can you update the fiddle with failing scenario ?

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu I edited the source array to mix up the property ordering.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu https://jsfiddle.net/s4fqeshf/1/

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu Still won't work, see https://jsfiddle.net/s4fqeshf/2/

Comment: @silverwind Thanks for pointing :) I have update the code. As per Zerkms,   i will look at it. Thanks Zerkms for pointing

Comment: @zerkms If we use the delimiter as `new Date().getTime()`, what is the chance of false positive results ? I hope it is less but i can agree, it is a string comparison overhead.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu please see the [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893291/filter-array-of-objects-for-unique-elements/29893756?noredirect=1#comment47912554_29893291) to the question for a **proper solution**.. The "chance" is a terrible way to develop, it's programming not lottery. The solution either works, or not.

Answer (score -3):

Use lodash! https://lodash.com/docs#uniq

> Creates a duplicate-free version of an array, using SameValueZero for equality comparisons, in which only the first occurence of each element is kept. Providing true for isSorted performs a faster search algorithm for sorted arrays. If an iteratee function is provided it is invoked for each element in the array to generate the criterion by which uniqueness is computed. The iteratee is bound to thisArg and invoked with three arguments: (value, index, array).

Include it in your HTML
`<script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>`

Then in your controller.

```
var filteredArray = _.uniq(arr, function(item, key, a) { 
    return item.a;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8xp3o7b3/3/

Comment: And "SameValueZero for equality" works for objects?

Comment: How about `b` and `c` properties? What makes `a` that special? What if the object does not have `a`?

Comment: Proof that this solution sucks: http://jsfiddle.net/8xp3o7b3/5/

Comment: you're right I'm just updating it. where is your solution?

Comment: I have closed a question as a duplicate: no reason to answer the same things multiple times. So, there is no *my* solution here - because there is some other guy's solution that is okay.